# Does MS Word secretly upload my file to cloud?

Tags: ms-word, cloud

When I open the "recently opened file" tab in MS word, I see that each file is marked with a green check:

[image]

The green check sign is usually used to indicate a file is uploaded and synced with cloud. But I never turned on any cloud sync, my onedrive app is not logined in.

[image]

Does it mean MS-word secrectly upload my doc anywhere?